# Using HTML 5 File API to load a JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, json, fileapi

I want the user to be be able to chose a JSON file on there computer, this JSON file should then be made available to the client side Javascript.

How would I do this using the FILE API, the ultimate goal is the the user selected JSON file to be available as an object which I can then play about with in Javascript. This is what I have so far:

```
JsonObj = null 



function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
     f = files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
         JsonObj = e.target.result
         console.log(JsonObj);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }



document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

**FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/jamiefearon/8kUYj/

How would I convert the variable JsonObj to a proper Json object, one can can add new fields to etc.

Comment: maybe this will help.  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: I have read the tutorial you have mentioned and have updated my answer to show you what I have got.

Comment: You've got a small syntax bug in your example. There's no semicolon after `JsonObj = e.target.result` (in the inner-most code block)

Answer (score 12):

Don't load the data as a "DataUrl" via `readAsDataURL`, instead use `readAsText` then parse it via `JSON.parse()`

e.g.

```
JsonObj = null 

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
     f = files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
         JsonObj = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
         console.log(JsonObj);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsText(f);
    }

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```